# What is the common type to golangs *ecr.ECR and *ecs.ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, factory, aws-sdk-go

I want to write a golang function which return the service according to the input:

```golang
func GetService(service string) <what to write here> {
    session, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(Region)})
    switch {
       case service == 'ecr':
        var svc *ecr.ECR
        svc = ecr.New(session)
        return svc
       case service == 'ecs':
        var svc *ecs.ECS
        svc = ecs.New(session)
        return svc
   }
}
```

It is kind of factory for aws services, but what is their common type which has to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is write two functions where each will return either of these.

Other option is to return an interface and let the user cast the value as he knows what it is. Optionally interface can have some methods defined if object share methods with same name.

Last approach that I see is most fitting is a modular approach that I will also demonstrate. But with pseudo code.

```
func NewSession
    session, err = (create session)
    (handle error)
    return session

// now lets use this
func MyUseCase
    ecr = NewEcr(NewSession())
    (use ecr)
```

The thing you are abstracting in your code should not be abstracted at all. User should create his instance as it is simpler then casting it and even faster.

The main goal of abstraction is simplify top level code and eliminate repetition. Keep that in mind.